# How can I apply groupby on django queryset

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-queryset

I have a queryset say,

```
a_query =  <QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user_id': 10, 'name': 'xyz'}, {'id': 2, 'user_id': 10, 'name': 'abc'},{'id': 3, 'user_id': 12, 'name': 'pqr'}]>
```

So here I want to apply groupby on user_id so the result should be,

```
[(10, [['xyz', 1], ['abc', 2]]), (12, ['pqr', 1])]
```

I tried using itemgetter and groupby but that doesn't   work.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/

Comment: Please show how you get the queryset in the first place. You should probably be doing the grouping directly in the db query.